# Is there a way to handle state in a form that is dynamically built based off of parameters sent from the back end

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I have a page in react 18 talking to a server which is passing information about how to build specific elements in a dynamic form. I am trying to figure out how to manage state in a case where there are multiple selects/multiselects in the page. Using one hook will not work separately for each dropdown field.

Code is updated with the latest updates. Only having issues with setting default values at this point. Hooks will not initially set values when given.

```
        import { Calendar } from 'primereact/calendar';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';
import { InputSwitch } from 'primereact/inputswitch';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';
import { MultiSelect } from 'primereact/multiselect';
import React, { useEffect, useState, VFC } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffectOnce } from 'usehooks-ts';

import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'redux/store';

import Form from '../components/ReportViewForm/Form';
import { getReportParamsAsync, selectReportParams } from '../redux/slice';

export const ReportView: VFC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const locState = location.state as any;
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const reportParams = useAppSelector(selectReportParams);
  const fields: JSX.Element[] = [];
  const depList: any[] = [];
  //const defaultValList: any[] = [];

  //dynamically setting state on all dropdown and multiselect fields
  const handleDdlVal = (name: string, value: string) => {
    depList.forEach((dep) => {
      if (name === dep.dependencies[0]) {
        dispatch(getReportParamsAsync(currentMenuItem + name + value));
      }
    });
    setState((prev: any) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  };
  //dynamically setting state on all calendar fields
  const handleCalVal = (name: string, value: Date) => {
    setState((prev: any) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  };
  //dynamically setting state on all boolean fields
  const handleBoolVal = (name: string, value: boolean) => {
    setState((prev: any) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  /*   function getInitVals(values: any) {
    const defaultList: any[] = [];
    values.forEach((param: any) => {
      defaultList.push({ name: param.name, value: param.defaultValues[0] });
    });
  } */

  const [state, setState] = useState<any>({});

  const [currentMenuItem, setCurrentMenuItem] = useState(locState.menuItem.id.toString());
  useEffectOnce(() => {}), [];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reportParams?.length === 0) {
      dispatch(getReportParamsAsync(currentMenuItem));
    }
    //reload hack in order to get page to load correct fields when navigating to another report view
    if (currentMenuItem != locState.menuItem.id) {
      window.location.reload();
      setCurrentMenuItem(locState.menuItem.id.toString());
    }
  }, [dispatch, reportParams, currentMenuItem, locState, state]);

  //dependency list to check for dependent dropdowns, passed to reportddl
  reportParams.forEach((parameter: any) => {
    if (parameter.dependencies !== null && parameter.dependencies[0] !== 'apu_id') {
      depList.push(parameter);
    }
  });

  //filter dispatched data to build correct fields with data attached.
  reportParams.forEach((parameter: any, i: number) => {
    if (parameter.validValuesQueryBased === true) {
      if (parameter.validValues !== null && parameter.multiValue) {
        const dataList: any[] = [];
        parameter.validValues.map((record: { value: any; label: any }) =>
          dataList.push({ id: record.value, desc: record.label }),
        );
        fields.push(
          <span key={i} className='p-float-label col-12 mx-3 field'>
            <MultiSelect
              options={dataList}
              name={parameter.name}
              value={state[parameter.name]}
              onChange={(e) => handleDdlVal(parameter.name, e.value)}
            ></MultiSelect>
            <label className='mx-3'>{parameter.prompt.substring(0, parameter.prompt.indexOf(':'))}</label>
          </span>,
        );
      } else if (parameter.validValues !== null) {
        const dataList: any[] = [];
        parameter.validValues.map((record: { value: any; label: any }) =>
          dataList.push({ id: record.value, desc: record.label }),
        );
        fields.push(
          <span key={i} className='p-float-label col-12 mx-3 field'>
            <Dropdown
              options={dataList}
              optionValue='id'
              optionLabel='desc'
              name={parameter.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleDdlVal(parameter.name, e.value)}
              value={state[parameter.name]}
              //required={parameter.parameterStateName}
              placeholder={'Select a Value'}
            ></Dropdown>
            <label className='mx-3'>{parameter.prompt.substring(0, parameter.prompt.indexOf(':'))}</label>
          </span>,
        );
      }
    } else if (parameter.parameterTypeName === 'Boolean') {
      fields.push(
        <span key={i} className='col-12 mx-3 field-checkbox'>
          <InputSwitch
            checked={state[parameter.name]}
            id={parameter.id}
            name={parameter.name}
            onChange={(e) => handleBoolVal(parameter.name, e.value)}
          ></InputSwitch>
          <label className='mx-3'>{parameter.prompt.substring(0, parameter.prompt.indexOf(':'))}</label>
        </span>,
      );
    } else if (parameter.parameterTypeName === 'DateTime') {
      //const date = new Date(parameter.defaultValues[0]);
      fields.push(
        <span key={i} className='p-float-label col-12 mx-3 field'>
          <Calendar
            value={state[parameter.name]}
            name={parameter.name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const d: Date = e.value as Date;
              handleCalVal(parameter.name, d);
            }}
          ></Calendar>
          <label className='mx-3'>{parameter.prompt.substring(0, parameter.prompt.indexOf(':'))}</label>
        </span>,
      );
    } else if (parameter.name === 'apu_id') {
      return null;
    } else {
      fields.push(
        <span key={i} className='p-float-label col-12 mx-3 field'>
          <InputText name={parameter.name}></InputText>
          <label className='mx-3'>{parameter.prompt.substring(0, parameter.prompt.indexOf(':'))}</label>
        </span>,
      );
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(state);
  };

  return (
    <Form onReset={null} onSubmit={onSubmit} initialValues={null} validation={null} key={null}>
      {fields}
    </Form>
  );
};

enter code here
```

Comment: how about passing the `parameter.name` (if it is a word with no spaces) along with your handle change functions, which modifies state accordingly? `onChange={(e) => handleDdlVal(parameter.name, e)}` where `parameter.name` is the key for the state in an object, which is set to e's value

Comment: That would work, but then I ran into the issue of having to re render the fields with their new values. I ended up implementing a parent-child formik relationship with the ddropdowns. This is a little skechy though because ill have to use formik to grab some values and not others.

Comment: what was the issue? I would expect it to be as easy as `value={state[parameter.name]}`. I may be missing how you have mapped your data here though. Do you perhaps have an example of the data you are using to create this?

Comment: If you can provide a codesandbox as a starting point, I am sure we can work something out.

Comment: very quick and dirty codesandbox about what I mean [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lichterman-mx5h9t?file=/src/App.js:1363-1371). The chosen options are seperate here, but can also be modified to update state in the store using dispatch.

Comment: @Gandzal That worked. Thanks for showing me, i didnt know you could use hooks with objects like that. I am having another issue. The parameter comes with a default value, but i dont see any good way of setting this since the hook is outside of the scope of the field and now value on all the fields is being set to state[parameter.name] where it used to be parameter.defaultValues[0]. Any insight?

Comment: The default state can be set within the hook initial value parameter, by creating an object with `paramName:defaultValue` key value pairs. I have updated the codesandbox with a function to do so. see `getInitialParamValues`

Comment: @Gandzal, thanks again for the help it looks like that will be the solution. That really showed the fundamental behavior of react my biggest issue is actually knowing what its capable of and your code really helped out, thank you so much!

Comment: @Gandzal I think i spoke too soon. Setting the default values this way does not work. No errors are thrown but the value of state is always undefined.

Comment: Can you modify my codesandbox to create the issue you are facing? if my method worked, where the initial default state can clearly be seen in a useEffect console log with the initial state object as a dependency, perhaps you are facing a stale closure when using it elsewhere

Comment: @Gandzal i think you are right, when I run the page it doesnt initially load in the values but if i move the code and save it works fine. Is that a timing issue in the design of my page?

Comment: I am unsure. I would need to see the code